# How to get value of selected item from dropdown menu using php

Tags: php

Hier i have a little issue. If you choose the same value in sequence (or if you click twice on submit button) nothing happend. But if you change the item from the dropdown list it's working good. The value of variable " var value=$(this).data("value");" does not change if you dont choose another item from the list. Why i want to change value because this variable value gets rows from database. I have tried change() function without any succes.

```
      <div class="col-md-6 center">
    <H2>Macig Box</H2>
    Please Select Nummer Of Match.
    <form id="myform" method="get">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
            Succes
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" id="selectedNummer" name="selectedNummer" />
        <ul class="dropdown-menu myCustomDropMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" onchange="change()" >

            <li><a href="#" data-value="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="5">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="6">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="7">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="8">8</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

        <script>
       $('.myCustomDropMenu li a').click(function(e){
     var value=$(this).data("value");
var selText = $(this).text();
$(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+'<span class="caret"></span>');
     $('#selectedNummer').val(value);
});
     </script>
     <script>
function change(){
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Can someone please help me to archive this goal. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you want a solution written in JS/jQuery as you've tagged those in this question, even though they seem unrelated. If so, please add the JS code you've written yourself to the question.

Comment: I thing i should remove these two tags, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've use jQuery to set the selected value from Dropdown to input field.

What you can do is, put a `click` trigger on `<a>` of dropdown menu, and on `click` of a `<a>` from dropdown set the corresponding value to `selectedNummer` input.

If there are multiple dropDownMenus on the page you can add a custom class to dropDown menu to put a specific `click` trigger.

So your HTML would look like this.

```
<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
    <H2>Macig Box</H2>
    Please Select Nummer Of Match.
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
            Succes
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" id="selectedNummer" name="selectedNummer" />
        <ul class="dropdown-menu myCustomDropMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#" data-value="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="5">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="6">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="7">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="8">8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And to set the value to `selectedNummer` input, JS would be

```
$('.myCustomDropMenu li a').click(function(e){
     var value=$(this).data("value");
     $('#selectedNummer').val(value);
});
```

Now when you submit the form using `POST` or `GET` method, you can access the value using `$_POST['selectedNummer']` or `$_GET['selectedNummer']`, and use that to assign value to PHP variable.

```
//e.g.
$variableValue=$_POST['selectedNummer'];
// OR
$variableValue=$_GET['selectedNummer'];
```

Working jsFiddle for setting the input value: https://jsfiddle.net/1dLoqe44/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it's help me very much.

Comment: The user said it helped him, not sorted the problem completely. I guess that's why you have a upvote on your answer. @Alok

Comment: This code works fijn, just one thing using this dropdown if you choose same value twice in sequence does not happend anything. I mean if you choose first two you get value of two after if you again choose two page does not reload. Any suggestion.

Comment: On which condition you're reloading the page?

Comment: Submit button seems do nothing if you don't change the value from dropdown list. I hoop i am clear.

Comment: Put this line `document.getElementById("myform").submit();` below `$('#selectedNummer').val(value);` and remove this line `onchange="change()"`.